# When changing props in redux all components are affected

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

When I mount my component `CommentFeed` it will call `getPost()` twice because I have two posts with separate CommentFeeds. Since each of those fields is listening to prop changes for comments the last CommentFeed(Post 2)doesn't have any comments and will causes my (Post 1) to have no comments. I was thinking about saving the states of the comments for each CommentFeed, but if I check prevState with nextProps theoretically should still override the comments of Post1 since technically the nextProp is different?

How do I even approach this? Please tell me if this doesn't make sense so I can clarify better

> Post 1:
>   has Comments
>
> Post 2: No comments (the getPost() of this CommentFeed removes the CommentFeed of Post 1)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import CommentItem from "./CommentItem";
import { getPost } from "../../oldComp/actions/postActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
class CommentFeed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { postId } = this.props;
    this.props.getPost(postId);
  }

  render() {
    const { postId, comments } = this.props;
    console.log(comments);
    if (comments === undefined) {
      return <div />;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          {postId}
          {comments.map(comment => {
            return (
              <div key={comment._id}>
                <CommentItem
                  key={comment._id}
                  postId={postId}
                  comment={comment}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

CommentFeed.propTypes = {
  comments: PropTypes.array,
  getPost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  comments: PropTypes.array,
  postId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  comments: state.post.post.comments
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getPost }
)(CommentFeed);
```

[image: Post 1 comments]

[image: Post 2 comments]

Comment: I think I talked myself through it and will use ShouldComponentUpdate() and just test it against the state literally how I talked about in the question. I'll post the solution. If this is the wrong thought process let me know

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you put getPost() in componentDidMount, it'll only be called once. This method is called a single time when the component first mounts, but won't get called on re-render. Async fetch actions in general go inside this lifecycle.

Comment: That's true, but when componentDidMount mounts the second post without the comments calls getPost() and all components waiting for the change get hit with it.